# core.js:4352 ERROR FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an index for category and id, but I still get this error. What can be wrong?

```
this.database
    .collection<any>('videos', (ref) => ref.orderBy('id', "asc").where('category', '==', category).limit(limit).startAt(doc["id"]))
    .valueChanges({ idField: 'docId' });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you're showing in the screenshot is an index on a **collection group**, while your code merely queries one collection. You will also need to define an index on the individual collection to allow this query.

Note that the link in the error message should take you exactly to the right page in the Firebase console with all fields prepopulated to generate the necessary index for that query.

Comment: I used that link, and index was created, but I still have the error, and when I click on the link, I see this now: "This index already exists The link you followed defines an index that already exists. Try running the query that generated the link again."

Answer (score 0):

Besides the note from [Frank van Puffelen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297339/13690331) answer, it seems in your code you are querying for `id` in `ascending` order. However, the picture you provided shows an index for a `descending` order. Which can be the reason that you receive the error. You should create a separate index for each `asc` and `desc` order.